# Texture doesn't want to change

Tags: texturing

The texture of my rocket launcher doesn't want to change, only a part of it however, as you can see in the pic below:

Information on the thing:
The part was copied from another model

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can add more info/a .blend file?

Comment: Is your texture assigned to the selected faces?

Comment: How do I assign them?

Comment: Nevermind, fixed it, it was assigned to the wrong material so I had to delete it, thanks for the hepl

Comment: Reminds me of: "How many psychiatrists does it take to change a light bulb? Perhaps just one, but... the light bulb has to *want* to change."